# php code doesent work when upload on server

Tags: php, html, mysql

My php code is not working when i am uploading on server.when i am running this on localhost its working fine..why??

```
<?php
ob_start();
include 'CUserDB.php';
session_start(); 
include 'config.php';
$myusername=$_POST['txtusername']; 
$mypassword=$_POST['txtpassword']; 
$typ= $_POST['type'];
$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$typ = stripslashes($typ);    
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword=mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);
 $typ = mysql_real_escape_string($typ);          
        try {
            $oUser = new CUserDB();
            $result = $oUser->Login($myusername,$mypassword,$typ);
            } 
        catch (PDOException $pe)
         {
            die("Error occurred:" . $pe->getMessage());
         }   
    if($result[0][0][UserName] != '')
        {
            session_start(); 
            $_SESSION['UserId'] = $myusername;
           if( $typ == "Dealer")
            { 
            header('location:Dealer/ManageProfile.php'); 
            }
           else if ($typ == "Individual")
            {
             header('location:Individual/managep.php'); 
            }
           else 
            {
             header('location:Builder/managep.php'); 
            }
        }
   else 
    { 
    header('location:header.php'); 
    }
?>
```

This is checklogin page when i am running this on server.after click on login this page is getting called.but on server it doesent redirect after login page it stays on checklogin.php page. why this is happening on server?

Comment: Is there anything in error log? May be a `header already sent` error...

Comment: What *is* happening on the server?  Is the PHP code being interpreted by the server at all?  (Or do you see it in the rendered page source?)  Is there an error in the PHP logs?  The web server logs?  If you add some additional debugging and logging to the code, where and how does it fail?

Comment: why i am down voted??? i cant even ask question??

Comment: Do you get any error message(s)? Set `error_reporting(E_ALL)` and `ini_set('display_errors', 1);`.

Comment: there is no any error message.echo is also not working.

Answer (score 2):

The Location header, according to http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html, should be an absolute URI, ex:

```
Location: http://yourserver/header.php
```

Also, the proper header name is `Location`, capitalized.
A space character should also be present between the colon character and the header value.

According to the PHP documentation:

> You can usually use $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] and dirname() to make an absolute URI from a relative one yourself:

```
<?php
/* Redirect to a different page in the current directory that was requested */
$host  = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$uri   = rtrim(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), '/\\');
$extra = 'mypage.php';
header("Location: http://$host$uri/$extra");
```

Now, I can't say for certain that your redirections won't work as you wrote them, there might be another problem, but you should try to respect the HTTP protocol as much as possible to avoid compatibility issues.

Comment: You should provide more details in your question, then, because this is all that appears somewhat wrong in the code. There must be an error that you don't see. Try to debug your code with XDebug and an IDE that works with it, that will help you a lot.

Answer (score 1):

1. Check your code doesn't have any syntax errors. Something like http://phpcodechecker.com/ should work fine.
2. Double check the files you include are actually being included. Try changing them to requires instead and see what happens
3. Make sure the the PDO extension is present and working. Do a quick `phpinfo()` and see what's enabled.
4. Enable errors (if they're not already) and work your way through them.